# Proof of Tarski's self-reference lemma

Tags: logic, fixed-point-theorems

In http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~dale/godel/godel.html, Tarksi's self reference lemma is mentioned but the proof is omitted.

> Tarski's Self-Reference Lemma. For any formula $p(x)$ in an adequate
>   theory, there is a sentence (formula without free variables) $s$ such that $s$ iff $p(<s>)$ where $<s>$ is the number which encodes $s$.

Can anyone show the reference to the proof, or the proof here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this lecture notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/24-242-logic-ii-spring-2004/lecture-notes/self_reference.pdf) by Vann McGee.